# Angularjs does not read button ID

Tags: angularjs

I've created an application where the structure has a list with ng-repeat that loads images with a link. The link in these images has a dynamic ID that should be read by a function called in ng-click ().

The problem is that the ID comes with undefined value.

this is my list:

```
<ul class="list-inline" id="team">
  <li ng-repeat="player in players">
    <a data-toggle="modal" id="{{player.id}}" class="modalPlayer" ng-click="loadModal()"  data-target="#myModal">
      <div class="infoPlayer">
        <h3 ng-bind="player.name"></h3>
        <hr>
        <small ng-bind="player.position"></small>
      </div>
      <figure>
        <img src="{{player.img}}" alt="{{player.name}}">
      </figure>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

and this is my function:

```
$scope.loadModal = function(){

var attribute = $('.modalPlayer').click(function(){
    var id = $(this).attr(id);
    alert(id);
  });
    alert(attribute);    
}
```

The function is inside the controller. I have already tried numerous possibilities to read the ID, but all without success. I would like something like:

```
var test = angular.element (document.getElementsByClassName ('myClass'). GetAttribute ('id');
```

thank for helpers

Comment: You're trying to register a click function with jQuery. use `ng-click` and pass it a function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do,

```
<a data-toggle="modal"  ng-attr-id="{{player.id}}"></div>
```

or simply pass the id to your function,

```
ng-click="loadModal(player)" 

$scope.loadModal = function(player){
    alert(player.id);
}
```